# How to add two different attributes to one line of a combobox in javafx?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I would like to show the name of my restaurants, which I get from a restaurant object in my ComboBox, and use the id of the restaurant when one restaurant name is choosen. Is there a way to add different attributes to a item of a Combobox, or what the best way is to solve that problem.

```
@FXML
ComboBox cb_restaurant;
ArrayList<Restaurant>restaurants;

public void onChoosenRestaurant(){

     int id = cb_restaurant.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();??????
     //It is here where i would like to have the id of the selected restaurant

}
public void onTableView(){

}
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    Database d = new Database();
    ObservableList<Restaurant> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    restaurants = d.getAllrestaurats();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i <restaurants.size() ; i++) {
        options.add(restaurants.get(i));

    }

    cb_restaurant.setItems(options);
```

Comment: Never use raw types. You should have a `ComboBox<Restaurant>`, not a raw `ComboBox`. Then you just do `int id = cb_restaurant.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getId();`, assuming `Restaurant` has a `getId()` method. As in the question @ItachiUchiha linked, use a cell factory to display the restaurant name (if the `toString()` method doesn't give you what you want).

Comment: BTW, you can replace `for loop` with `options.addAll(restaurants);`

Comment: @James_D Thanks for your comment. It was useful.